# Watchman doesn't notice changes on network folder

Tags: watchman

I am trying to get watchman running in order to monitor an NFS mounted folder.
I was able to get everything running within the local file system. 
Now, I have changed the config to monitor a network folder from my NAS. It is locally mounted.

Watchman server is running on the Linux client. 
All watchman commands on the Linux client.

```
watchman watch
watchman -- trigger /home/karsten/CloudStation/karsten/CloudStation/Karsten_NAS/fotos/zerene 'photostack' -- /home/karsten/bin/invoke_rawtherapee.sh
```

Folder is located on the NAS, according to 
mtab:

```
192.168.xxx.xxx:/volume1/homes /home/karsten/CloudStation nfs rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.xxx.xxx,mountvers=3,mountport=892,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.xxx.xxx 0 0
```

If I move files into the folder on the local machine they get recognized and watchman triggers the actions.
BUT if I move files into the same folder from a remote client connected to the same NAS folder nothing happens.

Any idea what I need to change to make watchman recognize the files dropped from another client into that folder?

Many thanks in advance
Karsten

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible.

From https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#system-requirements:

> Watchman relies on the operating system facilities for file notification, which means that you will likely have very poor results using it on any kind of remote or distributed filesystem.

NFS doesn't tie into the `inotify` layer in any kernel (the protocol simply doesn't support this sort of change notification), so you will only be able to be notified of changes that are made to the mounted volume by the client (because those are looped back through inotify locally), not for changes made anywhere else.